# mod_ruid RuidGid equivalent

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd

Since mod_ruid is no more supported by custombuild(directadmin) I had to install php-fpm. I would like to know where I can set the user that is running the website what was primarily the RuidGid in the httpd.conf.

Each users website was run primarily on apache with the **RuidGid [user][group]** set in their httpd.conf, where can I set/change this now?